# Syntax error on token(s), Misplaced construct(s) ,

Tags: java

The code below gives error on as defined by the commented line, can anyone tell me why?

```
public class Foundation {
    private int var1;
    default int var2; //Syntax error in tokens misplaced constructs, misplaced constructs
    protected int var3;
    public int var4;
}
```

Comment: Where did you read that `default` was a valid visibility modifier? It's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `default` access keyword. It's called *package-private* (default), but it means, that there is no access modifier:

```
public class Foundation {
    private int var1;
    int var2;
    protected int var3;
    public int var4;
}
```

Comment: complement (or different wording): it is sometimes called default access  control because there is no modifier.  I don't think this term  is used in the official language specification, instead "package access" is used.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, in oracle's tutorial it's called "default" or "package-private": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: probably default as in it is the default access control, that is, the one used if nothing else is given, no explicit modifier (as the tutorial states)

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, I've corrected the answer